# kafka java process consuming way too much memory

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jvm

I have  a kafka 0.11.xx sever with three nodes.
The machine on which the server is hosted is a linux Ubuntu machine with 4GB of RAM.
I can see the java process is utilizing around 90% of my RAM.
I have set the heap values to 5GB.

the process consuming the memory is **jre/bin/java -Xmx5G -Xms5G**

So is it a normal scenario where kafka is expected to run with a memory of 4-5 GB,or is it something not normal.

If its not the usual scenario,can you suggest a fix for this issue,or increasing the RAM would be the only answer.

Comment: It depends of what are you doing with Kafka

Comment: We have a few topics and we produce and consume messages.The activity is not that frequent though

Comment: `-Xms5G` literally means "grab 5GB of ram from OS when starting", it doesn't depend on load

Answer (score 6):

Kafka is [designed to use the memory available to it](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#persistence), as part of ensuring its high performance.

Linux also will [grab the memory it needs](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/) and this is not necessarily a bad thing.

I would only worry about the memory usage if your performance analysis determines that the machine is bottlenecked on available RAM.

Comment: "don't worry about it" -OP

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Somehow, you're setting the JVM heap parameters to 5GB.  But your server only has 4GB of physical RAM?  You need to leave memory for the OS, other ancillary applications/utilities, as well as Kafka, or you will run into issues.
- Kafka itself relies on off-heap memory (i.e. memory *outside* of the JVM) to serve consumers from there, so it doesn't have to read everything from disk all the time.  But again, you need to have that memory available.

Since you indicate there's not a lot of activity on the cluster, I would first start with setting the JVM arguments for the Kafka service (I'm assuming that's what you posted) to 2GB only, so: `-Xmx2G -Xms2G`.  And then see how it impacts your application/service.  Kafka would then have about 2GB+ of RAM for off-heap processing.

Comment: BTW Increasing the heap memory reduces the available native/off heap memory. So reducing the heap size can improve memory usage and performance.

Comment: So for a production ready 3-node kafka with relatively heavy message producing and consuming at regular intervals, would 4 GB of RAM with proper heap management (2GB heap) be enough or  should we consider increasing the RAM to 8GB with around 4GB of heap memory

Comment: Your best bet will be to test it.  Try the performance with 4GB RAM, and 2GB JVM heap.  This will probably be enough for your volume.  If anything, you might run into CPU or bandwidth bottlenecks before you run out of RAM.